# Accepting mouse scroll gestures in wxPython on Mac OS X

Tags: python, objective-c, macos, wxpython, pyobjc

On Mac OS X the trackpad has support for several gestures, one is the two fingered swipe to scroll up, down, left, or right on a page. wxPython has a panel to help create scrolled widgets wx.lib.scrolledpanel. However it does not have support for gestures which is a real pain.

I have tried to modify the NSView, as it is done if it were a normal Objective C application, however the NSEvents use methods (touchesBeganWithEvent:, etc) that are subclassed to be used as a notification and handling of an event. This is unlike the Bind calls in wxPython. This would be fine however if Objective C allowed monkey patching... eg

```
def handleTouchBegin(event):
    print "Hey a touch event has begun!"

view.touchBeganWithEvent_ = handleTouchBegin
```

but as you can guess PyObj C errors (because Objective C doesn't support monkey patching or not in any clean and nice fashion) and I get the following error

```
TypeError: cannot change a method
```

Ok well I could do what apple says and subclass it, but the object is already created, so how can I still capture the events. Of course there is also

```
NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask: 
and
NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:
```

but those also disappoint in that they either don't even deal with the application (global deals with all the others) or doesn't deal with a single NSView's events (or does it and I am misinformed).

So how should I do this? Am I missing another option, I know I read something about NSResponder but from what I gathered that is what NSView is, an event responder and you don't add one to a NSView.

Are there observers like in QTKit such as for monitoring the load state changing ( https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/QTKitApplicationProgrammingGuide/AnatomyoftheQTKFramework/AnatomyoftheQTKFramework.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008156-CH109-SW11 )?

Comment: You have an existing view, created by someone else, and you want to change its event handling?

Comment: Yes. Well I want to capture touch events on the track pad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ObjC doesn't support Python-style monkeypatching… but it does support some similar features like method swizzling, class posing, category interposition, etc. And PyObjC can do all of those things.

Off the top of my head, swizzling from PyObjC should look something like this:

```
def swizzle(cls, sel, func):
    oldimp = cls.instanceMethodForSelector_(sel)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return func(self, oldimp, *args, **kwargs)
    newmethod = objc.selector(wrapper, 
                              selector=oldimp.selector, signature=oldimp.signature)
    objc.classAddMethod(cls, sel, newmethod)
    return wrapper
```

Comment: So does swizzling replace the method or wrap it (e.g call it before or after it calls the original function)?

Comment: @Zimm3r: It replaces the method. But if you really don't know about ObjC method swizzling… well, I guess start [here](http://cocoadev.com/MethodSwizzling) and search for examples from there, because there are a lot of little details that will surprise you if you're more of a Python dev than an ObjC dev…

Comment: For what it's worth, I actually had to do something similar a couple years ago (using a different library, not wx, and wrapping a view created by a third-party lib… but the same basic idea). I found it easier to write an helper dylib in ObjC that my Python code just triggered via `ctypes` to a C function. Of course YMMV; it depends on whether you find the extra layers of PyObjC or the syntax and edit-compile-debug cycle of ObjC more of a burden…